# Casting compiled type to current namespace type

Tags: c#, silverlight, oop, design-patterns, casting

I am currently building an emulator in C#/Silverlight. Because we are emulating a particular software domain, we have domain-level classes (Cube, CubeSet, BaseApp, etc.) that we have to implement within the scope of our emulator. Additionally, these domain-level classes have to be available to the application developer because they are accessible to applications which will be emulated.

So what we have is a .dll which is a compilation of just the domain-level classes, and then within the emulator implementation itself we have a package of the same domain-level classes.

The goal is to dynamically instantiate the application object, which is doable, and then call a sequence of that application's methods to carry out the emulation. However, in calling one of the methods, we have to pass in a domain-level object which is instantiated within the emulator implementation. We have to call AssociateCubes (which takes a CubeSet parameter) on the dynamically instantiated application. When I try to do that dynamically, I'm getting an InvalidCastException which (amusingly enough) says that a "CubeSet" object cannot be cast as a "CubeSet" object. An example of the code being used to dynamically access the application is:

```
Object o = Activator.CreateInstance(appType);
MethodInfo AssocCubes = o.GetType().GetMethod("AssociateCubes");
AssocCubes.Invoke(o, new object[] { Cubes });
```

where Cubes is of type CubeSet in the emulator, and the appType is as given by the user.

Is there any way to force some sort of link between the two so that the compiler recognizes that in reality the same class, or is it that the two classes are completely distinct and cannot be associated in such a way to allow an object of one type to be cast as the other.

One solution I have considered is simply defining a method to manually copy the contents of one object to an instance in the emulator, but the problem therein is that the application developer can define their own methods for the application class to be used as helper methods.

I may not have explained everything completely, so I can offer any clarifications that may help expose a potential solution.

Comment: Have you looked at unittesting frameworks (like RhinoMocks)? They support such substitution of classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't want to discount the previous answer given, but I have found a solution as I described in the comment I wrote.

What I do instead is pull the domain layer out of the emulator project and compile it separately as a DLL. Now that DLL is referenced in the emulator and the separate applications, so when the types are loaded dynamically they are considered to be the same type after all.

Answer (score 1):

The InvalidCastException only shows last portion of full class name for convinience, but types are compared on full identity: Full Name (including namespaces) and assembly it is coming from (which may have strong name if signed).

Consider using Unit Testing framework for "mocking" objects. Or at least read on how such frameworks wrap classes.

The real fix is to use testable class hierarchies. Often using interfaces instaed of concreate classes help to solve this type if issues.

Comment: I'll certainly look into that. I'm wondering now though if it isn't possible to exclude the domain level from the emulator project itself. Then the emulator would reference the .dll and the application would reference the .dll. Would this resolve them to have the same "full identity," as you mention?

Comment: Glad you found solution that works - using the same classes is very good approach.